# extract values from replacement list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Solve returns a list of replacement rules

```
In: Solve[x + y == 3 && x - y == 6, {x, y}]
Out: {{x -> 9/2, y -> -(3/2)}}
```

I am only interested in the right hand side of these rules. To extract the right hand side I use substitution:

```
({x, y} /. sol)[[1]]
```

It gives

```
{9/2, -(3/2)}
```

This works, but it is not very elegant. You have to adapt the list of the variables, each time you solve for different variables. Is there a more general way to extract the right hand sides form a list of replacements?

**Edit** The number of variables and the number of solutions may both differ.

Comment: I think everyone uses practically the same.  Personally I use the equivalent form `x /. First@Solve[...]` (if there's only one solution---there might be two).

Comment: I think using ReplaceAll is in fact the elegant solution. If you get used to working with rules this  method offers a lot of flexibility (e.g. when dealing with the already mentioned multiple solutions).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I also think that what you are already using is the best way, but here is another one to toss into the mix:

```
Solve[x + y == 3 && x - y == 6, {x, y}][[1]] /. Rule -> (#2 &)
```

> ```
> {9/2, -(3/2)}
> ```

Comment: This doesn't return the complete set of solutions, when there are more than only one. A simple improvement would be deleting `[[1]]` or setting `[[All]]`. My approach seems to be a bit unnecessarily sophisticated.

Comment: @Artes that is a valuable note.  I was attempting to duplicate the result that the OP wanted and he used `[[1]]` too.

Comment: This works very well when deleting [[1]]. When solving for many variables (10), I don't want to specify these variables twice. I think this is much more elegant then substitution.

Answer (score 13):

**Update:** With Version 10 comes the convenient built-in function [`Values`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html?q=Values)  which can be used as an alternative to `Part` and `ReplaceAll`:

```
Values@@Solve[x + y == 3 && x - y == 6, {x, y}]
(* {9/2,-(3/2)} *)
```

or

```
Values@Solve[x + y == 3 && x - y == 6, {x, y}]
(* {{9/2,-(3/2)}}  *)
```

Another example - a ragged list of rules:

```
lst={{a->1,b->2},{c->3},{{d->4}},{e->5,{f->6,{g->7}}}};
Values[lst]
(* {{1,2},{3},{{4}},{5,{6,{7}}}} *)
```

---

**Original post:**

You can also use

```
  Solve[x + y == 3 && x - y == 6, {x, y}] /. (_ -> b_) -> b
```

or

```
 Solve[x + y == 3 && x - y == 6, {x, y}] /. Rule[_, b_] -> b
```

or

```
Solve[x + y == 3 && x - y == 6, {x, y}] // #[[All, All, 2]] &
```

Comment: Yet another variation: `Cases[Solve[x + y == 3 && x - y == 6, {x, y}], r_Rule :> Last[r], Infinity]`

Answer (score 12):

What about

```
res=Solve[x + y == 3 && x - y == 6, {x, y}];
res[[1, All, 2]]
```

that gives

```
{9/2, -(3/2)}
```

as you wanted. This should work while using `Solve` for any finite number of linear simultaneous equations.

Actually Rules in Mathematica has similar structure as list of `Length` two. You can see that if you replace `Rule` in a expression with `List`.

```
a1 = {a -> 2, b -> 3};
a1 /. Rule -> List
```

resulting to

```
{{a, 2}, {b, 3}}
```

This is an example that shows `List` is an intrinsic structure in Mathematica language and part specification simply works on rules. As expected

```
a2 = {{a, 2}, {b, 3}};
{a1[[1, 2]], a2[[1, 2]]}

{2, 2}
```

gives the same result for the `List` as well as the list of `Rule`.

Answer (score 8):

As others have already echoed, using `ReplaceAll` is in fact, the most commonly used way (and not considered inelegant). You can accommodate for varying variables by keeping a list of them separately. For example, you could do

```
vars = {x, y};
sol = Solve[x + y == 3 && x - y == 6, vars];
var /. sol // First

Out[1]= {9/2, -(3/2)}
```

However, if you feel using `ReplaceAll` like that is kludgy, then you can also use `OptionValue` which does exactly what you want:

```
OptionValue[sol, vars]

Out[2]= {9/2, -(3/2)}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can always just use indexing to get the rhs, though I find it makes your code less readable. For your example:

```
sol[[All,All,2]]
```

will give `{9/2, -(3/2)}`.
Which should work in general as the second "column" of a rule list is the rhs.

Answer (score 4):

It would be better to use the following :

```
{#[[1, 2]], #[[2, 2]]} & /@ Solve[x^2 + y == 4 && x - y == 2, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {{-3, -5}, {2, 0}}
> ```

Since in general given a system of equations may have more than only one solution.

Another more general approach is to use `Table`, because of different number of variables. 
For example when we have 3 variables in a system :

```
x^2 + y == 4 && x - y == 2 && x^3 + y - z^3 == 5
```

We could write :

```
Table[ #[[a, 2]], {a, 3}] & /@ 
       Solve[ x^2 + y == 4 && x - y == 2 && x^3 + y - z^3 == 5, {x, y, z}]
```

**Edit**

Instead of specifying how many variables there are we can just use this :

```
Column@Apply[List, #, {2}] & @ Solve[
             x^2 + y == 4 && x - y == 2 && x^3 + y - z^3 == 5, {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

or

```
Column@
   Apply[Composition[Part[#, 2] &, List], 
         Solve[x^2 + y == 4 && x - y == 2 && x^3 + y - z^3 == 5, {x, y, z}], {2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since V10, we have [`Values`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html):

```
Solve[x + y == 3 && x - y == 6, {x, y}]
Values@ %
(*
  {{x -> 9/2, y -> -(3/2)}}
  {{9/2, -(3/2)}}
*)
```

Or simply

```
Values@ Solve[x + y == 3 && x - y == 6, {x, y}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In this solution,you can don't care about the structure of expressions

```
Clear[x, y]
Solve[x + y == 3 && x - y == 6, {x, y}] /. Rule -> Set
```

> {{9/2, -(3/2)}}