# Converting a list of replacement rules into a list of real values

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

The following command outputs a list of replacement rules.

```
sol3 = Flatten[
   FindRoot[
             y@t /. NDSolve[{y''[t] == -10 - 3/10 Sin@#, y'[0] == 12 Sin@#, 
             y[0] == 0}, y[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}], {t, 2}] & /@ (Pi/180 Range[
             10, 80])];
```

How can I convert that list into a list of real values? eg. replace each 't->2.45' with 2.45

Comment: Maybe `t /. sol3`?

Comment: related (duplicate?) [Extract values from replacement list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3175/125)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get all the `t` values with the following.

```
sol3[[All, 2]]
```

There are many ways but another nice pattern matching solution

```
sol3 /. (_ -> a_) -> a
```

Cheers!

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Among many solutions, the clearest is :

```
Last /@ sol3
```