# Plot function the uses Solve

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

Can someone tell me why I get an error (and how I get around it) from `Solve` while I try to `Plot` a function like:

```
In[119]:= z[y_] := Max[Solve[x^2 == y, {x}][[All]] /. Rule -> (#2 &)]
          z[3]
          Plot[Max[z[x]], {x, 0, 3}]

Out[120]= Sqrt[3]

          During evaluation of In[119]:= Solve::ivar: 0.00006128571428571428` is not a valid variable. >>

          During evaluation of In[119]:= Solve::ivar: 0.06128577551020408` is not a valid variable. >> 

          During evaluation of In[119]:= Solve::ivar: 0.12251026530612244` is not a valid variable. >>

          During evaluation of In[119]:= General::stop: Further output of Solve::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

What I do: I solve an equation (x^2=y) where y is my variable. I store this in an array and take the maximum value as my function z. This works, as shown (z[3]=sqrt[3]). But I can't use this togther with the `Plot` function.

I can of course create a list and use `ListPlot`. But this isn't so useful in the real Problem that has poles and is thus not well described by an equidistant mesh or similar

Comment: @ PeMa: avoid using the name x. This works out fine: Plot[Max[z[t]], {t, 0, 3}]

Comment: @ PeMa: the construct Rule -> (#2&) is also new to me.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze that is unusual, and it's being used instead of `:>`. But, it works like `q[r,s] /. q -> f` where `q` is replaced by `f` which in this case is a pure function, so it evaluates. Different, but effective.

Comment: The trick is found here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3175/extract-values-from-replacement-list

Comment: @PeMa yes, Mr. Wizard is a good source of tricks. `[[All]]`, though, is not necessary as that is what is returned by default.

Comment: @ Dr. Wolfgang Hintze using t worked already, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is in the use of the variable `x`, which is used as a dummy variable in both the function `z[y]` and in the function `Plot`.
When you rename one of them, e.g.

```
z[y_] := Max[Solve[x^2 == y, {x}][[All]] /. Rule -> (#2 &)]
z[3]
Plot[Max[z[xx]], {xx, 0, 3}]
```

your code works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `Solve` is not `HoldAll`

```
In[42]:= Attributes@Solve
Out[42]= {Protected}
```

so that the plot variable, `x`, is being substituted into `Solve` in the variable specification. There are a couple of ways to prevent this, but the most effective in the long term is to uniquely rename `x` in `z`, as follows

```
z[y_] := Module[{x}, Max[Solve[x^2 == y, {x}][[All]] /. Rule -> (#2 &)]]
```

`Module` internally renames its variables so they are always unique, even between different executions. `Block` would work here as well.

---

For this particular example, though, I would use neither. I would have `Solve` do its job first, and then wrap it in a function, e.g.

```
Clear[z]
z[y_] = Max[Solve[x^2 == y, {x}] /. Rule[_,b_] :> b]
```

The difference is I used `=` (`Set`) not `:=` (`SetDelayed`), so that the right hand side is executed prior to it being turned into a function. In general, `Solve` will take a long time to execute, so this form is often superior in terms of performance.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks!