# Assigning the numerical results of Minimize to variables

Tags: expression-manipulation

I need to use the numerical values returned by `Minimize` in further computations. Consider,

```
Minimize[{x - y, -3 x^2 + 2 x y - y^2 >= -1}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {-1, {x -> 0, y -> 1}}
> ```

How can I assign the numerical values in this result to variables `a`, `b`, `c` such that `a = -1`, `b = 0` and `c = 1`?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "assign the results to a, b, c". Do you want to end up with `a == -1, b == 0, c == 1`?

Comment: yes, a,b,c are supposed to be used in calculating x,y values in loop

Comment: res = Minimize[...];
a = res[[1]]; {b, c} = {x, y} /. res[[2]]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3175/extract-values-from-replacement-list

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly:

```
{a, b, c} = Extract[{{1}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}]@
             {-1, {x -> 0, y -> 1}}
```

After this, `a == -1 && b == 0 && c == 1`.

Answer (score 3):

In V10, here are a few ways to use [`Values`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html):

```
{a = #, {b, c} = Values[#2]} & @@ 
 Minimize[{x - y, -3 x^2 + 2 x y - y^2 >= -1}, {x, y}]
(*  {-1, {0, 1}}  *)

{a, {b, c}} = Minimize[{x - y, -3 x^2 + 2 x y - y^2 >= -1}, {x, y}] /. 
  sol : {__Rule} :> Values[sol]
(*  {-1, {0, 1}}  *)

With[{minsol = Minimize[{x - y, -3 x^2 + 2 x y - y^2 >= -1}, {x, y}]},
 a = First@ minsol;
 {b, c} = Values@ Last@ minsol;
 ]
```

The last way, being more verbose, might also be considered more expressive.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the most clear way is something like

```
{a, {b, c}} = {#[[1]], {x, y} /. #[[2]]} &@
              Minimize[{x - y, -3 x^2 + 2 x y - y^2 >= -1}, {x, y}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the following three methods are clear and sufficiently verbose (and work in all MMa versions at least starting from version 5):

```
res = Minimize[{x - y, -3 x^2 + 2 x y - y^2 >= -1}, {x, y}];

Clear[a, b, c] 
{a, {b, c}} = res /. Rule[_, v_] :> v
```

> ```
> {-1, {0, 1}}
> ```

```
Clear[a, b, c] 
{a, {b, c}} = res /. r_Rule :> Last[r]
```

> ```
> {-1, {0, 1}}
> ```

```
Clear[a, b, c] 
{a, {b, c}} = res /. Rule -> CompoundExpression
```

> ```
> {-1, {0, 1}}
> ```

Accidentally I found that undocumented two-argument form of `Last` works in version 10.2 (but does not work in version 8.0.4):

```
Clear[a, b, c] 
{a, {b, c}} = res /. Rule -> Last
```

> ```
> {-1, {0, 1}}
> ```

Another alternative (this syntax form of `MapAt` was introduced after version 8):

```
Clear[a, b, c] 
{a, {b, c}} = MapAt[Last, res, {2, All}]
```

> ```
> {-1, {0, 1}}
> ```

And completely different approach (works in all MMa versions):

```
Clear[a, b, c]
a = First@Replace[res, {x -> b, y -> c, Rule -> Set}, {-1}, Heads -> True];
{a, b, c}
```

> ```
> {-1, 0, 1}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I think I'll go with this one.

```
 {a, b, c} = 
   With[{r = Minimize[{x - y, -3 x^2 + 2 x y - y^2 >= -1}, {x, y}]},
     Extract[r, Position[r, _?NumericQ]]]
```

Comment: `Cases[r, _?NumberQ, {-1}]` is a bit shorter. Another way: `Level[r, {-1}][[;; ;; 2]]`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov. I thought someone had already posted the `Cases` case.