# How to use quantities obtained by solving equations directly to plot

Tags: plotting

I want to know how we could use the quantities we found by solving simultaneous equations, directly into plotting graphs. For example I have this *Mathematica* code; it gives the values of `a` and `b` but does not plot.

```
Clear[a, b] 
Solve[{a + b == 30, 2*a + 3*b == 50}, {a, b}]
Plot[a*x + b*x, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: See [(18393, ans. 18706)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18706#18706) for advice.  See also [(3175)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3175/extract-values-from-replacement-list), [(6669)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/assign-the-results-from-a-solve-to-variables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to do

```
sol = First@Solve[{a+b==20,2a+3b==50},{a,b}];
Plot[a x + b x/.sol,{x,0,10}]
```

`Solve` gives you a list of `Rule`s. Here, there's just one such rule, but it's still wrapped in an "extra" set of braces because It's a *list* of rule*s*. Use `First@` (equivalent to wrapping the expression in `First[]`) to get the first element of that list, which is your desired `Rule`.

Using `/.` just lets you plug the rule from 'sol' into your equation; *i.e.* `a x + b x /. sol = a x + b x /. {a->10,b->10} = 10x + 10x = 20x`, which you can `Plot`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben, it really works. Actually it was for a bigger project than that and really helpful, saved a lot of work for me.

Comment: Happy to help. Remember to search the documentation; it's extremely helpful! Be sure to read through [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18706#18706) as well, as @Michael E2 suggested.

Answer (score 2):

```
sol = Solve[{a + b == 20, 2 a + 3 b == 50}, {a, b}]
```

> {{a -> 10, b -> 10}}

See [ReplaceAll (/.)](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) and [Applying Transformation Rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html)

```
point = {a, b} /. sol
```

> {{10, 10}}

```
ContourPlot[{a + b == 20, 2 a + 3 b == 50}, {a, 0, 15}, {b, 0, 15}, 
Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point@point}]
```

[image]